# Adding shortcut in PHP Autoload causes conflict on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I would like to ask you why I'm getting conflict error after added this to composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Models\\": "app/Models/",
        "Controllers\\": "app/Http/Controllers/"
    },
    ...
}
```

and namespace everything inside such as **"app\Models\People\Admin.php"** be

```
namespace Models\People;
```

I have searched for this problem before with no luck, did I miss something?

Thank you!

Comment: Would you show us the full error message?

Comment: @RaedYakoubi The last error message looks like this:
_Cannot declare class Models\People\Admin, because the name is already in use_

Answer (score -1):

You are getting this error because the autoloader is including all of the classes under `App\` first, which includes all of the classes under `App\Models` and `App\Controllers` too, then re-including these classes again, which causes this conflict.

To illustrate this, here is what is happening:

1. The autoloader recursively looks for all classes under the `app` directory.
2. It then of course finds the `app/Models/People/Admin.php` and `include`s it.
3. After it is done with autoloading all of the classes under `app/`, it starts looking for class files under `app/Models`, finds the `Admin.php` class file and `include`s it once more.
4. The error is thrown, because for PHP you are doing something like:

```php
class Admin {}
class Admin {}
```